# HTML Source Code Different from the content displayed in browser

Tags: html

I observed that Yahoo is somehow able to "hide" the content that it displays in the browser as compared to what we see in the webpage's source code.

For example, if you visit https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AOTG/profile/ in any standard browser, then in the bottom right corner you'll find the section titled "Fund Summary" with the text "The fund is an actively managed exchange-traded fund (ETF) that invests in U.S. listed equity securities that have high growth potential...."

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

If I try to do view-source of this webpage/frame, then this section and its text is not visible at all. Like, try searching for "The fund is an actively managed" text in the view-source, and nothing will match.

What is it that Yahoo is using to hide the content in source code, and is it possible to be decoded through the source-code to get the text displayed in the browser?

1. How to hide the content like Yahoo (asking as a website creator)
2. How to access the content in the source-code (asking as a bulk user)

Comment: They aren't hiding it. It's just dynamically added by some script. It is possible to get that content through the source code, otherwise the browser would not be able to do so.

Comment: Thanks @EmanuelP, but that's the exact question. How to "get that content through the source code"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not visible in the page source, because it is generated by a script. The page source only shows the state of the page when it is delivered by the server, without any script-generated code.

To see the generated html of the page, you could right click in this part of the page and choose "inspect element" (or a similar named option, depending on the browser), you will then see the generated code, which differs from the page source.

If you want to find the script which is generating the part of the code you have to find some unique id or data attribute of the code and search through all files  in the debugger tab in the developer tools. This will take some time to get used too. How you can do that depends on your browser, just search for "developer tools" of your browser for more details.